# Is it "Probably yes" or "Probably, yes"?

Tags: american-english, punctuation, commas

Is it **"Probably yes"** or **"Probably, yes"**?

Comment: Is there a pause between the words when you say it?

Comment: Probably one or the other.

Comment: **:D** Thanks, guys! 
I got the answer I was looking for. **:)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even so short a string has different interpretations partially distinguished by the punctuation.

- *Probably, yes*. / (and certainly *Probably ... yes*.)

usually shows an on-the-hoof corrective/firming-up change/modification of answer.

- *Probably yes*.

usually shows that the answer to the prior question is probably (in the answerer's estimation) *yes*.

But there are different interpretations to these fragments; context (or full sentences) is needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge with me and the others, Edwin Ashworth. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with, "Probably, yes."  With only the one word, yes, to follow the adverb, probably, these phrases say the same thing.  And, the word, yes, isn't a verb.

Look, to write that, "Maybe, I found an answer," involves the likelihood an answer was found.  Whereas, "Maybe I found an answer," questions who it was that  could have found it.